# How do I do graphics in Python?

Tags: python, graphics

So I made some games in Python, but they are all text-based because I can never find out how to do graphics. I have done a bit of searching, and the answers that I have found either don't work or don't answer my question. I am wondering how to use graphics and implement them in code, such as if a red dot touched a blue one the red one will turn green, or if I press the up arrow key the red dot will move up. I know that is a lot to ask, so I am wondering if there is a website or something that can tell me where and how to start.

Comment: This kind of question is usually closed because of too opinion based. But in this particular case the obviously correct answer is [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/).

Comment: library/module suggestions are out of scope for Stack Overflow. That being said, `pygame`, `tkinter`, or a more minimal `turtle` are good starting points.

Comment: What have you researched so far? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried a module that I can't recall, I think it was "py" something. But when I put it in the compiler, it gave me an error stating that it didn't work. I am going to try out some other things right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Axe319 mentioned you can use, pygame, Tkinter, or turtle although there are more. You can find information on pygame here https://www.pygame.org/news, but if you have a Mac it can be tricky to use. Pygame is probably more of the more popular ones to use, however more recently people have been using other modules. tkninter is usually used for GUI, but you can use it to make some games. Turtle graphics as he said again are minimal and I have only used them to make pictures, but I know people have made games. Based on what you wrote Pygame, or Tkinter would work best, and if it is simple enough use tkinter. They both have plenty of tutorials on the internet if you need help.